# Error creating EKS node-group with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-eks

While I am trying to deploy EKS via Terraform, I am facing an error with node-group creation.
I am getting the following error:

```
Error: error waiting for EKS Node Group (Self-Hosted-Runner:Self-Hosted-Runner-default-node-group) to create:
unexpected state 'CREATE_FAILED', wanted target 'ACTIVE'.
last error: 1 error occurred:i-04db15f25be4212fb, i-07bd88adabaa103c0, i-0915982ac0f217fe4:
NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster. 
with module.eks.aws_eks_node_group.eks-node-group,
│   on ../../modules/aws/eks/eks-node-group.tf line 1, in resource "aws_eks_node_group" "eks-node-group":
│    1: resource "aws_eks_node_group" "eks-node-group" {
```

EKS

```
# EKS Cluster Resources
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks" {
  name = var.cluster-name

  version = var.k8s-version

  role_arn = aws_iam_role.cluster.arn

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [var.security_group]
    subnet_ids         = var.private_subnets
  }

  enabled_cluster_log_types = var.eks-cw-logging

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.cluster-AmazonEKSClusterPolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.cluster-AmazonEKSServicePolicy,
  ]
}
```

EKS-NODE-GROUP

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "eks-node-group" {
  cluster_name    = var.cluster-name
  node_group_name = "${var.cluster-name}-default-node-group"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.node.arn
  subnet_ids      = var.private_subnets
  capacity_type   = "SPOT"
  node_group_name_prefix = null #"Creates a unique name beginning with the specified prefix. Conflicts with node_group_name"
  scaling_config {
    desired_size  = var.desired-capacity
    max_size      = var.max-size
    min_size      = var.min-size
  }
  update_config {
    max_unavailable = 1
  }
  instance_types = [var.node-instance-type]
  # Ensure that IAM Role permissions are created before and deleted after EKS Node Group handling.
  # Otherwise, EKS will not be able to properly delete EC2 Instances and Elastic Network Interfaces.
  depends_on = [
    aws_eks_cluster.eks,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.node-AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.node-AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy
  ]
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.cluster-name}-default-node-group"
  }
}
```

IAM

```
# IAM

# CLUSTER
resource "aws_iam_role" "cluster" {
  name = "${var.cluster-name}-eks-cluster-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "cluster-AmazonEKSClusterPolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.cluster.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "cluster-AmazonEKSServicePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.cluster.name
}

# NODES
resource "aws_iam_role" "node" {
  name = "${var.cluster-name}-eks-node-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "node-AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.node.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "node-AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.node.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "node-AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
  role       = aws_iam_role.node.name
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "node" {
  name = "${var.cluster-name}-eks-node-instance-profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.node.name
}
```

Security Group

```
# Create Security Group
resource "aws_security_group" "cluster" {
  name        = "terraform_cluster"
  description = "AWS security group for terraform"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.vpc1.id

  # Input
  ingress {
    from_port   = "1"
    to_port     = "65365"
    protocol    = "TCP"
    cidr_blocks = [var.address_allowed, var.vpc1_cidr_block]
  }

  # Output
  egress {
    from_port   = 0             # any port
    to_port     = 0             # any port
    protocol    = "-1"          # any protocol
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] # any destination
  }

  # ICMP Ping 
  ingress {
    from_port   = -1
    to_port     = -1
    protocol    = "icmp"
    cidr_blocks = [var.address_allowed, var.vpc1_cidr_block]
  }

  tags = merge(
    {
      Name = "onboarding-sg",
    },
    var.tags,
  )
}
```

VPC

```
# Create VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc1" {
  cidr_block           = var.vpc1_cidr_block
  instance_tenancy     = "default"
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = merge(
    {
      Name = "onboarding-vpc",
    },
    var.tags,
  )
}


# Subnet Public
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_public1" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.vpc1.id
  cidr_block              = var.subnet_public1_cidr_block[0]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = "true" #it makes this a public subnet
  availability_zone       = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]

  tags = merge(
    {
      Name                     = "onboarding-public-sub",
      "kubernetes.io/role/elb" = "1"
    },
    var.tags,
  )
}

# Subnet Private
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_private1" {
  for_each                = { for idx, cidr_block in var.subnet_private1_cidr_block: cidr_block => idx}
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.vpc1.id
  cidr_block              = each.key
  map_public_ip_on_launch = "false" //it makes this a public subnet
  availability_zone       = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[each.value]

  tags = merge(
    {
      Name                              = "onboarding-private-sub",
      "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb" = "1",
      "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster-name}" = "owned"
    },
    var.tags,
  )
}
```

tfvars

```
#General vars
region = "eu-west-1"

#Bucket vars

bucket             = "tf-state"
tag_name           = "test"
tag_environment    = "Dev"
acl                = "private"
versioning_enabled = "Enabled"

# Network EKS vars
aws_public_key_path        = "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
aws_key_name               = "aws-k8s"
address_allowed            = "/32" # Office public IP Address
vpc1_cidr_block            = "10.0.0.0/16"
subnet_public1_cidr_block  = ["10.0.128.0/20", "10.0.144.0/20", "10.0.160.0/20"]
subnet_private1_cidr_block = ["10.0.0.0/19", "10.0.32.0/19", "10.0.64.0/19"]

tags = {
  Scost       = "testing",
  Terraform   = "true",
  Environment = "testing"
}

#EKS
cluster-name        = "Self-Hosted-Runner"
k8s-version         = "1.21"
node-instance-type  = "t3.medium"
desired-capacity    = "3"
max-size            = "7"
min-size            = "1"
# db-subnet-cidr      = ["10.0.192.0/21", "10.0.200.0/21", "10.0.208.0/21"]
eks-cw-logging      = ["api", "audit", "authenticator", "controllerManager", "scheduler"]
ec2-key-public-key  = ""
```

```
"issues" : [ {
        "code" : "NodeCreationFailure",
        "message" : "Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster",
```

What do you think I missed configured?

Comment: Have you configured a way for the instances in the private subnet to communicate over the Internet? You are missing either a NAT Gateway or the IAM roles/policies are not sufficient. Take a look at the error you are getting on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html.